# How should I optimization mysql setting to avoid slow query problem?

Tags: mysql

In my DB have some table have over 150,000 records inside, and always got the warning that there has slow query problem.

Installed myself in windows server with only MySQL running. The server has 24 thread and 32 GB Ram. Using SSD.

Here is my.ini setting:

```
[mysqld]
port=3306
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="SERVER1.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="SERVER1-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
log-error="SERVER1.err"
log-bin="SERVER1-bin"
server-id=1
report_port=3306
lower_case_table_names=1
secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads"
max_connections=5000
table_open_cache=10000
tmp_table_size=16G
thread_cache_size=10
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=6G
key_buffer_size=4G
read_buffer_size=2G
read_rnd_buffer_size=2G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=25G
innodb_log_file_size=512M
innodb_thread_concurrency=65
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=24
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=1G
max_allowed_packet=1G
max_connect_errors=100
open_files_limit=60000
sort_buffer_size=1G
table_definition_cache=10000
binlog_row_event_max_size=256K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
```

Comment: You might want to provide more specific information, like some of the queries, whether or not they are all slow or just for some tables or some types of queries, etc.  I doubt that it is related primarily to your server config, but  to the queries and the structure of the database.

Comment: Need a query, `EXPLAIN {query}`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tbl name for each table}`.I Its more likely to be a poor query/table structure than a tuning issue.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN to see why the query is slow. Always do that and work on doing it in the SQL before you randomly start changing configuration values. And we can't tell you how to optimize the SQL when you don't post the SQL and the EXPLAIN. You're asking us to speculate on how to fix something that you're not providing any meaningful information about, and we can't do it. The way to optimize SQL starts with looking at the EXPLAIN and SQL.

Comment: You have 32G of RAM and yet your my.ini asks for MORE than 32G when you look at your requests.  Please use mysqlcalculator.com to enter Your Values to see the magnitude of your RAM that could be used.  Use ALL defaults suggested in your my.ini except innodb_buffer_pool_size of 24GB and your system will perform much better.  After stop/start or restart and you have been running for 24 hours then download the Windows version of MySQLTuner.pl (perl) from this URL https://github.com/pmachapman  Post the results of MySQLTuner for assistance in choosing the suggestions to apply, please.

Answer (score 0):

You should create index on the columns which is used for joining and can extend innodb_max_buffer_size parameter value

Thanks